# how to find records that do not have a value in the foreign key column in extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

In extbase, how can I find all records that do not have a value in the foreign link column.

I have a model that can relate to a different object. The relation is 1:n and it is called "dayend".

I now create a query like this in the responding repository:

```
$query->equals("dayend", null);
```

This does not work, meaning that constraint is completely ignored. The original value in that column is "0". Thus, I also tried

```
$query->equals("dayend.uid", 0);
```

However, this throws an error: "Could not determine type of relation."

My goal is to get all objects that are NOT related to any "dayend" object. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, in my first example, the line is constraint is not being ignored but the query results in an empty query result.

Comment: Just two ideas, not tested: use `$query->isEmpty("dayend");` or use something like `$query->statement("SELECT * from <your table> WHERE dayend IS NULL AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0");`.

Comment: isEmpty does not exist in extbase: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/8596. I now use the statement. Thanks.